# Insert infobox in a new table of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I use a float enviroment in order to change the caption of my figures, such as:

```
 \newfloat{infobox}{tbp}{ext}
 \restylefloat*{infobox}
 \floatname{infobox}{my_picture}
```

I works fine, but I can't figure out how to add it to a new table of figures (pictures), such as:

```
\newcommand{\listinfoboxname}{my pictures}
\listofinfobox
```

Comment: I haven't read any documentation on infoboxes, but aren't you missing an underscore in the `\newcommand` part?

Comment: If you mean 'my_picture' instead of 'my picture', there is not a problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple. Just add the following line to the table of contents:

```
\listof{infobox}{my pictures}
```