# modify the style of the contents table

Tags: table-of-contents

After solving this issue [Insert infobox in a new table of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340756/insert-infobox-in-a-new-table-of-figures) regarding infoboxes in a table of contents, I deal with a new problem. I want to inherit the style of 'list of tables' and 'list of figures' to the 'list of infoboxes' as well.

So, using the `titletoc` package, I change the tables style like this:

```
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
```

The same goes for the figures list:

```
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
....
```

Yet, when I use:

```
\titlecontents{infobox}[0em]
....
```

nothing happens *(the infobox list doesn't inherit a style)*. Indeed, in page 14 of *"The titlesec, titleps and titletoc Packages"*, I read that *(where `infobox` equals to `section`)*
:

***section*** is the section name without backslash: `part`, `chapter`, `section`, etc. `figure` and `table` are allowed too.

So, since I use a new environment *(infobox)*, and insert it in a table of contents, how could I modify the style of the contents table?

Comment: There's a command `\contentsuse` if I recall. But this question really should have a MWE: start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` with all the pieces needed to reproduce the problem and none of the pieces that have nothing to do with the problem. So I expect that about the only package loaded here would be `titletoc`, and you have some `infobox` and you have your non-working command and some minimal content to be typeset.

Comment: @jon You are right about the MWE comment. I try to minimize the code because it is adapted from a complex template.  By the way, I didn't find a `\contentuse` command. Thank you.

Comment: The `titlesec` documentation explicitly mentions `\contentsuse{ name }{ ext }`. Your example is far too minimal; please revise. Your job is to provide people who want to help you with an actual `.tex` file that demonstrates the problem, but does not include things irrelevant to the problem. As it is, we have to try to recreate a problem we don't currently face, and there's a danger that we will recreate the *wrong* problem, which won't help you and will represent a waste of time for the would-be helper.